# Proper way to access JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json, response

I have this simple statement to call a JSON response. It was working until recently I found out it stopped working. Not sure why its not working. Here is my code. Its very simple.

```
//Here is the response from the API
{"country":"US","state":"NY","city":"GLEN COVE"} 

$zip = "11542";
$url = "http://ziptasticapi.com/".$zip;
$info = file_get_contents($url);
$info = json_decode($info);

$cityname = $info->city;
$statename = $info->state;
```

Not sure why its not picking up the data at the end. I even tried changing it to json_decode($info,true) and changing it to $info['city'].

Comment: Did you try a var_dump, or print_r on $info to quickly see at least what it decoded as? If so, could you post that to your question?

Comment: @Randall I keep getting "1" with print_r

Comment: Try it on $info before you decode with json_decode. It may be the file_get_contents is not actually pulling the data you expect.

Comment: If the URL is correct, check if file_get_contents is blocked. Sometimes file_get_contents is blocked in some hosting due to security.

Comment: It might be the issue, as I just copy/pasted that code, and I get this for print_r: `stdClass Object
(
    [country] => US
    [state] => NY
    [city] => GLEN COVE)`

Comment: I think that may be the case. I got "1" again after get_file_contents. I will have to check the hosting securities in the php settings. Besides that, does anybody recommend any other hosting service where they dont turn it off allow_url_open?

Comment: your code just works as-is for me (copy-pasted into my `testanyhing.php`). Some networking issue ?

Comment: You could try to see if your host supports using the curl functions. Its a way to grab that data into a variable to parse/use. But if they locked down allow_url_open, they may have locked down curl too :(

Comment: Ok I just checked my php settings and allow_url_fopen is still on. I tried grabbing information from the google places API and that worked fine.

Comment: Don't abuse "free" APIs, even the ones that pretend like they don't have limits. Eventually you're going to get blocked, which is what I suspect has happened. Plus it's not like ZIP codes change, cache the responses.

Comment: Your code is fine, works for me.

Comment: @Sammitch I have another site. Im going to load the code there. Let me see if I got blocked. Will let you know in a few.

Comment: @Sammitch ok so I took the code to a basic html site. No wordpress or cms site and still no luck. Only thing I could think of now is its got to be is my server settings since both of my sites are hosted on same server. Not sure what else to change besides allow_url_fopen.